# how i can redirect to user-home page with this code

Tags: php

i am trying to redirect my login page to user-home page. my code is not showing any error but login page is not redirecting to user-home page. badly expecting a proper solution. Thanks in advance. the following image is the databse details of signup page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UulI5.png)

**here is my code of index page**

enter code here

```
<tr> 
<td width="200px" height="70px" style="color: gray;"><b>ENTER USERNAME</b></td>
                            <td width="100px" height="70px" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;color: gray;" ><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="ENTER USERNAME" style="width: 150px;height: 35px;background:none; border: none;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="200px" height="70px" style="color: gray;"><b>ENTER PASSWORD</b></td>
                            <td width="200px" height="70px" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;color: gray;" ><input type="PASSWORD" name="password" placeholder="ENTER PASSWORD"style="width: 150px;height: 35px;background: none; border: none;"></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="login"style="width: 150px;height: 35px;  background:none;border-radius: 10px; border-color: gray; padding: 10px  "></td>
                        </tr>
                    </form>

                        <h2>dont have an account signup here</h2>
                        <li><a href="signup-form.php">signup</a></li>





                    </table>

                    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
                    {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = $db->query("select * from signup where username = '$username' && password = '$password'");
    $count = $query->rowcount();
    $row = $query->fetch();
    if ($count > 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
     header('location:user-home.php'); 
    }else{
     header('location:index.php'); 
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: your HTML is not valid - the `FORM`, `h2` and `li` cannot inhabit the location you have above - the `li` can only be a child of `ul`, `ol` or similar list.

Comment: your sql code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use `passwqord_hash` to hash the password before saving to db. Is the layout of your page as above - with HTML then the PHP with `session_start`??

Comment: Try to use any encryption for the password field

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following condition

```
if($count > 1){
}
```

If there's an entry with the associated username and password in the database then `$query->rowcount();` will return the no of rows selected which should be one(1).
The condition should be

```
if($count == 1){
  //home-page
}
else{
 //index page
}
```

Comment: still its same no change.

Comment: Try Printing(echo) the value of $count before the if condition. Make sure you are using valid credentials to log in.

Note: If there are duplicate entries use the following condition
if($count >= 1){
  //home-page
}
else{
 //index page
}

Answer (score 0):

Please change  `if ($count > 1){}` to  `if ($count > 0){}`

Your code looks like :

```
if ($count > 0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
     header('location:user-home.php'); 
    }else{
     header('location:index.php'); 
    }
```

Comment: if ($count > 1){

session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
 header('location:user-home.php'); 
}else{
 header('location:index.php'); 
     }
 } 
to  if ($count > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
 header('location:user-home.php'); 
}else{
 header('location:index.php'); 
}
}
?>

Comment: should it be like this

Comment: @MimHsan :  yes,   the same